# I must click twice to work change the language in my Android app

Tags: android

I already tried to make App android change language and I have problem, my app must click twice to work change language.

Io I mean, when I first click English Button to change language is not work then I click again, it works.

**This is the method I'm using in Class Activity_Login.class**

```
public void showLanguageOptions() {
        String[] languages = {"Indonesia", "English"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity_Login.this);
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_dialog_changelanguage));
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_language);
        builder.setItems(languages,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                        if (arg1 == 0) {
                            ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).saveDefaultLanguage(Cons.LANG_ID);
                        } else {
                            ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).saveDefaultLanguage(Cons.LANG_EN);
                        }

                        ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).finish();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                                Activity_Login.class);

                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        builder.create().show();
    }
```

**and this is my `setuplanguage()` method in BaseActivity.Class**

```
public void setupLanguage() {
        Locale locale = new Locale(getDefaultLanguage());

        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;

        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }


    public String getDefaultLanguage() {
        return sharedPreferences.getString(Cons.USER_LANGUAGE, Cons.LANG_ID);
    }

    public void saveDefaultLanguage(String lang) {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putString(Cons.USER_LANGUAGE, lang);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

i called method setupLanguage to Activity_Login.Class

```
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_login);

         tv_language = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_language);

        String language = sharedPreferences.getString(Cons.USER_LANGUAGE, Cons.LANG_ID);
        setupLanguage();
        Log.d("bahasa",language);
        tv_language.setText((language.equals(Cons.LANG_EN) ? getString(R.string.text_english) : getString(R.string.text_indonesia)));

        tv_language.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                showLanguageOptions();
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: where did you call your `setupLanguage()` method?

Comment: in onCreate above method showLanguageOptions

Comment: @AkhileshPatil in onCreate above method showLanguageOption()

Comment: @MegiFernanda can u update all code where are u using both method showLanguageOptions() and setupLanguage() in ur activity.

Comment: @rockstar i already update sir

Comment: @Megi please check with debug. Because this is working well with my system I have tested.

Comment: @rockstar how about array_lang, array_lang_key and Strings value, what not to be made?

Comment: I have used ur array "languages" for alert dialog. And for Shared preference key used "lang" key by default... For first time in default used sp.getString("lang", "Indonesia");

Comment: @rockstar yes, i did like you. but why click twice must work

Comment: I'm facing the same issue yet. Any solution?